# Adjust label printing to the size of the label

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm working on a label printing software using c# and winforms. I've been trying to adjust the image I want to print, depending of the size of the label. The user can tell the software if the label size is 50*50, 40*40 or 40 diameter. But the software prints the image not as expected.

Here's the solution I tried: changing the paper size in the parameters of the printdocument, but I still have troubles.

If someone has an idea, thanks to help me…

```
PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("Carré 40x40", 157, 157);
paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
```

Here's what I get in the right with the above lines, and what I get when I remove them.

[image]

If that wasn't clear, let's say I want my software to be able to switch between different settings like we can do here:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: *But the software prints the image not as expected*. What is the actual result then? *but I still have troubles*. What troubles? Where's the code that prints the Bitmaps?

Comment: I've Added a before/after photo to help you